# Iterated sum and mean

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data with two columns as shown below. i am trying to estimate a standard deviation of the second column for each of the values of the first column. So 284, 285 and 286 values should have their consecutive standard deviation values.

```
284 4
284 9
284 6
285 0
285 1
285 3
286 9
286 3
286 1
```

I managed to calculate the running sum, but am stuck on the mean value calculation. Here is my code so far:

```
b = [(line.split("\t")) for line in data]
sums = [(sum(float(v) for k, v in g)) for k, g in groupby(b, key=itemgetter(0))]

lens = [(len(float(v) for k, v in g)) for k, g in groupby(b, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

`sums` works fine and calculates the summation per each change of the first column, however `len()` does not work and crashes with message:

```
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: Did you try searching *that exact error message*?

Answer (score 3):

The error is in this part of the code:

```
len(float(v) for k, v in g)
```

That is equivalent to:

```
len(g)
```

The generator the error is referring to is the list comprehension you are doing inside the brackets. If you actually wanted to perform the action you've written (and I don't think you do), the code would need to be:

```
len([float(v) for k, v in g])
```

Comment: It's a duplicate question, no need for an answer, since the existing ones are good already. :)